# What kind of user-level abstraction should I use for hierarchical tags?

Tags: icons, naming, categories

By user-level abstraction I mean what should I call them and what kind of icon should I use to represent it in the UI?  The concept of tags should be familiar to most users right now, but I'm not so sure hierarchical tags are, nor does the abstraction of tags completely fit.

What I have is actually something between folders and tags, in that each subtag is a proper subset of its parents.  To get the contents of a folder-tag-thing you take its contents plus the contents of its sub-folder-tag-things and do that recursively.  In a way they're like (and here's where I just partially answered my own question in the process of asking it) categories.  What do you guys think of calling them categories?  What kind of icon would you give it, since a category is an abstract concept rather than a physical object that can take a shape?

(Can wiki if requested)

Edit: For clarification, what I'm looking for is an abstraction for an end-user like Aunt Sally that easily grasp the concept.  Ideally there is also a graphical representation (an icon) that can be easily associated with that concept.

Edit2: One thing I did forget to mention is that an item can exist in more than on category (much like how Google Doc allows you to add an document to multiple folders).    I guess I've kind sold myself on calling them categories.  It just fits everything you can do with them.  Something can belong to a more than one category, subcategories make sense,  most subcategories people normally create lend themselves to an is-a relationship (for example, a Windows user might have say a folder called resumes in their My Documents folder, because a resume is a document, it would make sense that it's in My Documents as well if you think of the folders as categories)

What I still haven't figured out is the icon (I'm 99% sure I'm going to be using some kind of TreeView to display them in)  I could just use a folder icon I suppose, maybe a custom folder-like icon unless anyone else has a better idea.  Google calls them folders, so I guess it can't be too bad right?

To clarify further, my target audience will be people technical enough to know how to download and install the app, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

If your target audience is technical then TreeViews and/or Folders are common ways of abstracting hierarchical data.  They're all variants of the Composite pattern.

In the post-google era though, I've tended to consider hierarchical categorization less important than a flat tag/label space combined with a very fast search.  IMHO if the size of the dataset is large (e.g., > 1000 documents/elements) then the overhead of hierarchical categorization overwhelms the nominal benefit of having documents placed into nice neat categories.

If your target audience is non-technical then it's been my experience that non-technical users do not get hierarchies and won't take the time to to figure out more than a single level of categorization.

Comment: "non-technical users do not get hierarchies and won't take the time to to figure out more than a single level of categorization"  Really?  What about the Windows folder structure?  I think most people who use a computer have at least a basic understanding of hierarchies.

Comment: My experience is that Aunt Sally doesn't understand Windows folders. I'm not sure I understand the organization of windows folders.

Comment: I agree with le dorfier.  I asked where their music files are on the disk. Answer: "It's in iTunes" .

Comment: Hmm... my parents understand the folder structure and I had to spend an hour explaining to them how to install Live Messenger (this was over the phone and they didn't tell me that they got a new computer with Vista so I was confused about what mysterious dialogs they were talking about)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the answer comes from the Opera Desktop Team blog (as well as Dotclear’s blog, which used the same convention and thanks to whom I discovered it too):

`tag:subtag`
- `CSS:font`

When you click on the CSS:font, you know it is part of a larger CSS tag. The tag page should have a text indicating that a parent tag is available (or you can find it by yourself, much on Wikipedia with direct URL manipulation).

I have [a discussion running on WordPress](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/290016?replies=1#post-1138483).

Answer (score 0):

You could use "bundles" (as del.ico.us does). I am not sure if more than one level is meaningful for tags though.

Answer (score 0):

How about a tag "detail"?  Since a subtag is a proper subset, it can be thought of as applying detail to a tag...

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like an outline to me.

There's the [Outline Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OML) (OML).

Comment: Perhaps specifically if the content to contain were document fragments, but that aside it doesn't really work in the more general case and certainly an end-user would be confused if the user manual referred to them as outlines

Comment: "Tags" sure implies "document" to me. What are we talking about otherwise? "Category", "bundle", nor "detail" signify hierarchy in any sense. If it's semantically hierarchical, I think "outline" is legit. Otherwise it's context-free and there's no answer.

Comment: A tag is just a label, and that's the abstraction.  People understand what it means to put a label on something, like a physical object.  You can put a more than one label/tag on something and that's why the abstraction works better than say putting one thing in more than one folder.

Comment: There's nothing hierarchical about a label. @davyb, you wrote the question, do you want to retract the hierarchical part? You used categories, which also don't imply hierarchy, just distinct collections. Are they just links? I'm confused. :D

Comment: Maybe I need to work on my communication skills huh?  Anyway, my intent was to say that folders show hierarchy, but the idea that the same thing can exist in more than one folder doesn't make sense.  Tags allow that, something can have more than one tag, but hierarchy doesn't make sense.

Comment: So I wanted something where both concepts make sense simultaneously.  A category can have subcategories.  In fact that's what inheritance is based on, the is-a relationship.  A "siamese cat" falls under the category of "cat" as well as "mammal", "animal", and "living thing"

Comment: Although specifically in this analogy an item would be more like an instance of "siamese cat" say one named "Dolly".  In an OO sense, categories are like classes and items are like instances.